# How can i get the info from api request into an object

Tags: c#, json

When i use the following:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(postMethod.ToString()).Result)
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var Json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(Json);

        var y = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PersonInfoJson>(Json);
        Console.Write("r= " + y.requester); 
        Console.Write("id= " + y.id);
    }
}
```

The json returned is

```
{"requesters":[{"active":true,"address":null,"background_information":null,"can_see_all_changes_from_associated_departments":false,"can_see_all_tickets_from_associated_departments":false,"created_at":"2022-12-15T21:07:22Z","custom_fields":{"blah_id":"00002342"},"department_ids":[1111111],"department_names":["Student"],"external_id":null,"first_name":"mike","has_logged_in":false,"id":123456,"is_agent":false,"job_title":null,"language":"en","last_name":"ishere","location_id":null,"location_name":null,"mobile_phone_number":"111-111-1111","primary_email":"email@email.com","reporting_manager_id":null,"secondary_emails":["anotheremail@email.com"],"time_format":"12h","time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","updated_at":"2023-02-03T16:59:41Z","vip_user":false,"work_phone_number":"222-222-2222"}]}
```

I am trying to add it to the object above to get the id however that entire json is being dumped into the `y.requester` variable instead of each of the listed variables like in the following object:

```
public partial class PersonInfoJson
{
    public string requester { get; set; }
    public string department_names { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string job_title { get; set; }

    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string mobile_phone_number { get; set; }
    public string primary_email { get; set; }
    public string secondary_emails { get; set; }
    public string work_phone_number { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get the info after the line section that says `{"requesters":`

currently `var y = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PersonInfoJson>(Json);` puts that entire string into `public string requester { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the response, "requesters" element is actually array. So according response you should have c# objects like this:

```
public class CustomFields
{
    public string blah_id { get; set; }
}
    
public class Requester
{
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public object address { get; set; }
    public object background_information { get; set; }
    public bool can_see_all_changes_from_associated_departments { get; set; }
    public bool can_see_all_tickets_from_associated_departments { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public CustomFields custom_fields { get; set; }
    public List<int> department_ids { get; set; }
    public List<string> department_names { get; set; }
    public object external_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public bool has_logged_in { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool is_agent { get; set; }
    public object job_title { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public object location_id { get; set; }
    public object location_name { get; set; }
    public string mobile_phone_number { get; set; }
    public string primary_email { get; set; }
    public object reporting_manager_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> secondary_emails { get; set; }
    public string time_format { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public bool vip_user { get; set; }
    public string work_phone_number { get; set; }
}
    
public class Root
{
   public List<Requester> requesters { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize you response like:

```
var y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Json);
```

If you want to have nice c# variables names, use Attributes like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "work_phone_number")]
public string WorkPhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Btw, you can simply find online convertors from json to c# classes.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it exits with error 0 as soon as it hits var y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Json);   when i stepped through the program after reverting back to my original code i noticed that the items in question are returning as follows:  dictionary<string,object>  and when i dump the json into a dictionary as requested it then has the following Object<Arraylist>   and inside the Arraylist are more dictionary<string,objects>    If I am able to dump the original json into the initial dictionary which gives the AL, how can i turn that array list into a new dictionary

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix the type of these properties

```
public partial class PersonInfoJson
{
    // ... your other properties

    public string[] department_names { get; set; }
    public string[] secondary_emails { get; set; }
    
}
```

and use this code to deserialize

```
var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 
PersonInfoJson personInfo= JObject.Parse(json)["requesters"]
                         .ToObject<List<PersonInfoJson>>()
                         .FirstOrDefault();

 Console.WriteLine("id= " + personInfo.id);
```

you can not get a requester because your requester is a list of PersonInfoJson objects